# Session expiry changes every time

Tags: python, django, session, django-rest-framework

After creating a session, when I tried to get session the value of expiry date changes every time.

1st get request - `"session_expiry": "2022-02-21T22:42:38.231938Z"`

2nd get request - `"session_expiry": "2022-02-21T22:53:00.524236Z"`

3rd get request - `"session_expiry": "2022-02-21T22:53:26.022811Z"`

In all three cases values are of same session.

Comment: How are you creating a session ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 through rest Api using user id and mail

Comment: session setting in settings.py

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1060 * 60 * 24
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = env('SESSION_COOKIE_PATH')
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = env('SESSION_COOKIE_NAME')
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = env('SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY')
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = 'auth_cache'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = env('SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = env('SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE')
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = env('CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN')
DEFAULT_HASHING_ALGORITHM = 'sha1'

Comment: i think it is creating new session each time, maybe create a singleton session object, which gives same user same session till it is not expired?